# Why RDS does not use Amazon root certificate for SSL connection

Tags: amazon-web-services, ssl, amazon-rds

According to [the documentation of RDS](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/UsingWithRDS.SSL.html), it is required to install a specific public certificate ("rds-ca-2019-root.pem") to use RDS with SSL.

However, Amazon has a public certificate "Amazon Root CA" which is already installed on most OS.

Is there any reason for RDS, which is a service of Amazon, to not use the "Amazon Root CA" and instead use a custom certificate that the users have to install themself on their servers? And more generally is there any reason to use different certificate providers instead of the same every time?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From their [announcement](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/urgent-important-rotate-your-amazon-rds-aurora-and-documentdb-certificates/)

> The SSL/TLS certificates for RDS, Aurora, and Amazon DocumentDB expire and are replaced every five years as part of our standard maintenance and security discipline.

The current cert for Amazon Root CA meanwhile doesn't expire until 2037.

The use case here is obviously different, the expectation is for users of RDS, Aurora and DocumentDB to keep their app maintained at least every five years, while the Amazon Root CA is intended for applications where deploying new CA root certificate is expensive or impossible.